# Send gzip files node server

Tags: node.js, express, server, gzip, node-modules

I'm learning how to send gzip file in a Node.js server.

This is the very simple code running on my server now:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path    = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {  
    response.render('pages/index');
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

My gzip file is a JavaScript file inside a folder at the following path:

> public/zipped/file.js.gz

I'm trying to use one of this two npm plugins [npm i http-static-gzip-regexp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-static-gzip-regexp), [express-static-gzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip) but I'm not enable to make them work.

- For the first plugin I get this error

> Cannot find module 'http-static-gzip-regexp'

I include it with the following code:

```
var staticGzip =  require('http-static-gzip-regexp');
```

- While with the second plugin I don't manage to make it work, this is my code:

> ```
> var expressStaticGzip = require("express-static-gzip");
> app.use("/", expressStaticGzip("/zipped"));
> ```

Have you some suggestion or advice to make me understand how can I manage to make it work?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem using the [compression npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compression).

I've installed the package and then added the following code:

```
var compression = require('compression');
app.use(compression());
```

Now it perfectly works ;).

Comment: Hi, @Jacob as per my understanding, this will compress files for each request. Have you came across a strategy in which the file is already compressed, but just need to serve them. So that there's less load on the server to compress the files on ad hoc basis?